# Python : Calculate values and send in email

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-requests

**UPDATE :** I have corrected my code and below is working fine as expected

Basically i need an output like below in mail.
I achieved this. but need to know if any efficient code then below one.

name 5001   5010    9000    4 %

name    5002    5010    9000    4 %

name    5003    5010    9000    4 %

name    5004    5010    9000    4 %

1. Storing the values in list.

Below are dummy values

```
container = []
for server in range(1,5):
    container.append('name')
    container.append(server + 5000)
    container.append(5000+10)
    container.append(4000+5000)
    container.append(2500 % 12)

    print('\n' + str(container))
```

2. Assign list of values to msgBody in order to send it via email

I'm just putting piece of code here. Below also working fine

msgBody1 = ''

for count in range(4):

```
if count == 0:
    tempValue = '\n' + '\n' + str(container[count]) + '\t' + str(container[count+1]) + '\t' + str(container[count+2]) + '\t' 
    + str(container[count+3]) + '\t' + str(container[count+4])
    msgBody1 = msgBody1 + str(tempValue) + ' %'


elif count == 1:
    tempValue = '\n' + '\n' + str(container[count+4]) + '\t' + str(container[count+5]) + '\t' + str(container[count+6]) + '\t' 
    + str(container[count+7]) + '\t' + str(container[count+8])
    msgBody1 = msgBody1 + str(tempValue) + ' %'


elif count == 2:
    tempValue = '\n' + '\n' + str(container[count+8]) + '\t' + str(container[count+9]) + '\t' + str(container[count+10]) + '\t' 
    + str(container[count+11]) + '\t' + str(container[count+12])
    msgBody1 = msgBody1 + str(tempValue) + ' %'


elif count == 3:
    tempValue = '\n' + '\n' + str(container[count+12]) + '\t' + str(container[count+13]) + '\t' + str(container[count+14]) + '\t' 
    + str(container[count+15]) + '\t' + str(container[count+16])
    msgBody1 = msgBody1 + str(tempValue) + ' %'
```

Any other better and short code to replace msgBody1

Thanks in advance

Comment: It looks like you're mixing up integer indexing to a list (which must be numeric) and dictionaries.  What is `server`? A number? String?  Please provide example input.  But basically this is failing because initially the program is trying to access `a[0]` (because count==0) when `a` is an empty list.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clear; the code example does not make any sense. But from the structure of it, it seems like you are trying to use dict, but you are defining or sourcing lists.

Not sure why `for server in servers`, I hope your servers list is collection of numerical value, which does not make any sense.

Please go through list Vs dict, and list.append() and how to add new key, value pairs to dictionary.

Comment: I have updated my question. Can you suggest if any feasible code ?